# Extjs Grid - Click event listener

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, click, gridpanel

I did successfully add a row double click event listener to my grid by:

```
listeners : {
    itemdblclick: function(dv, record, item, index, e) {
        alert('working');
    }
},
```

Now, I need to get the exact value in third column at the selected row, how can I do that ?

**EDIT**

Okay found it:

```
listeners: {
    itemclick: function(dv, record, item, index, e) {
        alert(record.get('name'));
    }
}
```

but seems like the result of `record.get('name')` is not a text! its an object but I cannot handle it as if it a text. any body has any idea ?

**EDIT**

For example, if I pass the name to search function: `Search(record.get('name'));` this won't work. but if I pass it this way: `Search('Mike');` it works !

Comment: Will you know which column is bound at the third? IE, do you already know the dataIndex?

Comment: Are you sure? What object does `record.get()` give you?? If your data is a string, it'll give you a string. Can you inspect it in a debugger?

Comment: yes I am sure, I got the name as string successfully but when I pass it to another function, it can't handle it, on the other hand if I pass the name itself (I type it), function works fine.

Comment: you can look at your record data using `console.log(record.data)` or in your case `console.log(record.get('name'))`. don't use alert()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ensure that

- Your property name is really lowercase 'name' and not 'Name'
- Print the value of the field into the console with `console.log(record.get('name'))` or use the direct access by typing `console.log(record.data.name)` or `console.log(record.data['name'])`. Basically all should return the same.
- To cast a value to string apply `''` on the fly like `var myVar = 2; myVar = myVar + ''; // now print 20 as string`

Answer (score 0):

Try with,

```
listeners: {
itemclick: function(dv, record, item, index, e) {
 var selectedRec = dv.getSelectionModel().getSelected();          
 alert(selectedRec.get('name')); //Will display text of name column of selected record
}
```

Comment: got this error: `Object [object Object] has no method 'getSelected'`

Comment: @Noon You cannot call `getSelected()` this before 4.x. Use `getSelection()` instead. But doing this without mutliselection turned on in case of a click-event is not recommend, you have already the record as second argument!